# How to utilize intranet bandwith

Tags: intranet

Hi
Is it possible to measure which web pages are visited mostyy and download their contenet so
that people can access them offline.

Basic scheme is:

There will be client software on each user PC which will extract domain information on http requests and decide if it's already available on server or not.

On the server side there will be another software which updates downloaded web pages.

Do you think is this a good way of utilizing intranet bandwith ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Squid](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/AboutSquid): Web browsers can then use the local Squid cache as a proxy HTTP server, reducing access time as well as bandwidth consumption.